# jQuery scroll down buttons won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery and I'm wondering why my scroll down button won't work. I have been looking at several forum feeds but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work. Here I'd like for the link-button with id="this_button" to make a smooth jump to id="group2".

The script to make the smooth scroll is pretty basic and has already been seen multiple times, so I can't figure out what I did wrong. If any of you has an idea of how to solve this, it'd be grateful (Does the parallax layers influence badly ?). Also, if something is not clear, don't hesitate to ask.

```js
div = document.getElementById("div1").clientHeight;
  list = document.getElementsByClassName("else");
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].style.lineHeight=div-14+"px";
  }
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").on('click', function(event){
      if (this.hash !== ""){
        event.preventDefault();
        var hash = this.hash;
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top}, 800, function(){
          window.location.hash = hash;
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Dosis';font-size: 19px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header{
  background-color: white;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  z-index:1000;
}

header div{
  margin:auto;
  width:100%;
  overflow: auto;
  /*border:1px solid black;*/
}

header div ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin:auto;
  width:100%;
}

header div ul li{
  float:left;
  /*border: .5px solid red;*/
}

header div ul li a{
  display:block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  transition: color .3s;
}

header div ul li a.first{
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-right:30px;
}

header div ul li a.else{
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-right:20px;
}

header div ul li a.active{
  color:tomato;
}

#h2title{
  margin-bottom:0px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}

header div ul li a:hover:not(.active){
  color:tomato;
}
/*===========================================================================*/
.parallax {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.parallax__group {
  position: relative;
  height: 150vh;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 50vh 0;
}

.parallax__layer--base {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  border:1px solid black;
}

.parallax__layer--back {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
 /* centre the content in the parallax layers */
.title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
}

.huge{
  font-size: 400%;
}

#group1{
  z-index: 2;
}

#group1 .parallax__layer--back{
  background-color:black;
}

#group2{
  z-index: 5;
}

#group2 .parallax__layer--base{
  background-color: white;
}

.button{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  padding: 11px 25px;
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 72%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  outline:2px solid black;
  transition: .4s;
}

.button:hover{
  background-color: rgb(255,99,71,0.3);
  outline: 2px solid white;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="div1">
    <ul>
      <li style="position:relative; top:10px;">
        <a class="first" href="sthenos.html">
        <h2 id=h2title>STHENOS MOVEMENT</h2>
        <p style="margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px; margin-bottom:0; padding-bottom:0;">Lausanne</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li><p><a href="sthenos.html" class="active else">Accueil</a></p></li>
      <li><p><a href="sthenos.html" class="else">Toi dans tout ça</a></p></li>
      <li><p><a href="sthenos.html" class="else">Services entreprises/autorités</a></p></li>
      <li><p><a href="sthenos.html" class="else">À propos</a></p></li>
      <li><p><a href="sthenos.html" class="else">Contact</a></p></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<body>
  <div class="parallax">
    <div id="group1" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back"></div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">MASTER YOUR <span style="color:tomato">BODY</span>.</div>
        <div class="huge title">STHENOS MOVEMENT</div>
        <div>
          <a href="#group2" class="button" id="this_button">Découvrir l'association</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group2" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">BIEN</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I didn't get it ,
you wanna generalise it for every `a` or for specific button

Comment: Initially, i wanted to set that every "a" with a href being an id can just to said id. I'm sure if this was clear. 
For example, i have a first "a" : <a href=#1>blablabla</a> and a second "a" : <a href=#2>blablabla</a>. And i want the first one to jump to the div/section with the id="#1" and the second one to jump to the div/section with the id="#2".

Answer (score 0):

It's just about hash property you use it's not functional with query, so instead you can do something like that

```js
// I have commented that part because it's not related to the question

/*var div = document.getElementById("div1").clientHeight;
  list = document.getElementsByClassName("else");
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].style.lineHeight=div-14+"px";
  }*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").on('click', function(event){
              
      if ($(this).attr('href') != ""){
        event.preventDefault();  
        var hash = this.hash;
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 800, function(){
          window.location.hash = hash;
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Animation</title>
    
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="div1">
    <ul>
      <li style="position:relative; top:10px;">
        <a class="first" href="sthenos.html">
        <h2 id=h2title>STHENOS MOVEMENT</h2>
        <p style="margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px; margin-bottom:0; padding-bottom:0;">Lausanne</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li><p><a href="sthenos.html" class="active else">Accueil</a></p></li>
      <li><p><a href="sthenos.html" class="else">Toi dans tout ça</a></p></li>
      <li><p><a href="sthenos.html" class="else">Services entreprises/autorités</a></p></li>
      <li><p><a href="sthenos.html" class="else">À propos</a></p></li>
      <li><p><a href="sthenos.html" class="else">Contact</a></p></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<body>
  <div class="parallax">
    <div id="group1" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back"></div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">MASTER YOUR <span style="color:tomato">BODY</span>.</div>
        <div class="huge title">STHENOS MOVEMENT</div>
        <div>
          <a href="#group2" class="button" id="this_button">Découvrir l'association</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group2" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">BIEN</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Try this, it is working.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("a").click(function() {
   scrollToAnchor(this.name);
});

});
function scrollToAnchor(aid){
  var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
  $('.parallax').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},5000);
}

</script>
```

Comment: This seems to work for jumping to the class "parallax". What was wrong with my initial code ? How can i adapt this to make it work for a jump to a div with an id ? (#group2 for example).

Comment: You are messing name of <a> tag

Comment: Do not toss away code without explanation, please edit your answer (and maye remove the irrelevant parts?)